# Postgres 'collation "NOCASE" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist'

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am trying to setup a fresh database on a new system but I got this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject) collation "NOCASE" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
LINE 4:  email VARCHAR(120) COLLATE "NOCASE" NOT NULL, 
                            ^

[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    email VARCHAR(120) COLLATE "NOCASE" NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
)
]
```

I haven't changed anything but this works in 2 different computer and one of them runs Postgresql 10. I run this query using SqlAlchemy upgrade just for info.

I created database using this:

```
CREATE DATABASE db
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'tr_TR.utf8'
    LC_CTYPE = 'tr_TR.utf8'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Comment: Maybe someone [created](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcollation.html) that collation manually on those servers where it works.

Comment: I installed postgres on both machines (Linux and Windows Server 2008). I didn't make additional configuration on both. Collation in Windows machine (Postgres 10) is Turkish_Turkey.1254, but it just come as default.

Comment: Well, `"NOCASE"` is not a built-in collation. If that statements works on one installation, then that collation **must** have been created manually.

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/985da4c506133bb5d4f09697fd0a4b504ba834f3/test/requirements.py#L1252) suggests that your SqlAlchemy client is using the SQLite dialect, not the Postgres dialect. Check your configuration.

Comment: I checked the other system and there is nothing related to 'nocase' in Postgres. There can be more than one user using same email address. Interesting that SqlAlchemy didn't warn me before, or I just missed. But still it created tables without problem.

Answer (score -1):

In place of "NOCASE" you can use "CITEXT"  as this worked for me

So in your case in place of "NOCASE_UTF8" use "CITEXT" and before this add a line - CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;

As in Postgres, you would typically use a different collation for achieving a case-insensitive comparison.

Postgres offers the citext data type for case-insensitive text comparison, which you can use directly for your column. Here's how you can create your table using citext